# Is Arquillian Drone + Graphene dying?

Tags: jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

I have been using Arquillian Drone + Graphene for few months, I absolutely love it. This framework is nice to use. I do not see any updates to the git hub repo / twitter updates / people who are using it very often. So I am little bit concerned if i can continue using it.

Is it dying?

Comment: For more info on Arquillinan Graphene: http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automation-using-arquillian-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not. There were two releases of Graphene in May and Drone reached 2.0.0.Final earlier this year. Rest assured those libraries are still under development and there will be more to come! I would assume they have reached a level of being quite stable so there is not that much new things coming in and not that many things to fix at the same time.

If you have any suggestions how to improve just get in touch with the team, either through GitHub or JIRA.